# Shader code not working

Tags: hlsl, directx12

While compiling the following code. I get a error

```
float tess = saturate((gMinTessDistance - d) / (gMinTessDistance - gMaxTessDistance));

// Rescale [0,1] --> [gMinTessFactor, gMaxTessFactor].
vout.TessFactor = tess;
```

if i do this it works.

```
float tess = saturate((gMinTessDistance - d) / (gMinTessDistance - gMaxTessDistance));

// Rescale [0,1] --> [gMinTessFactor, gMaxTessFactor].
vout.TessFactor = 0.4;
```

..

```
struct VertexOut
{
    float3 PosL       : POSITION;
    float3 NormalW    : NORMAL;
    float3 TangentW   : TANGENT;
    float2 Tex        : TEXCOORD;
    float  TessFactor : TESS;
};
```

Here is code for vertex shader part

```
VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;

    // Transform to world space space.
    vout.PosL = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorld).xyz;
    vout.NormalW = mul(vin.NormalL, (float3x3)gWorld);
    vout.TangentW = mul(vin.TangentL, (float3x3)gWorld);

    // Output vertex attributes for interpolation across triangle.
    vout.Tex = mul(float4(vin.Tex, 0.0f, 1.0f), gTexTransform).xy;

    float d = distance(vout.PosL, gEyePosW);

    // Normalized tessellation factor. 
    // The tessellation is 
    //   0 if d >= gMinTessDistance and
    //   1 if d <= gMaxTessDistance.  
    float tess = saturate((gMinTessDistance - d) / (gMinTessDistance - gMaxTessDistance));

    // Rescale [0,1] --> [gMinTessFactor, gMaxTessFactor].
    vout.TessFactor = tess;

    return vout;
}
```

Im in Directx 12 Shader model 5.0

Comment: _"I get a error"_ You'd get better help if you included the error you got.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?